# Parent div not growing with floated children

Tags: css

I have an issue with my floated child divs not growing with my parent div. Is there a way to fix this? I need the wrapper to be 100% of the content in either div. Here is the html;

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="leftpane">

            <div id="lefthead">

                <div id="leftheadfiller">

                </div>

                <div id="leftheadlogo">

                </div>

                <div id="leftheaddivider">

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="leftcontent">

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="rightpane">


            <div id="righthead">

                <div id="rightheadfiller">

                </div>

                <div id="rightheadlogo">

                </div>

                <div id="rightheaddivider">

                </div>

            </div>


            <div id="navigation">

                Properties Careers About Blog Advertise Contact

            </div>


            <div id="rightcontent">

            </div>


        </div>


        <div id="close">

        </div>

    </div>


</body>
```

And here is the css;

```
html,body {
background-image:url('images/background.gif');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: aqua;
height: 100%;
width: 866px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#leftpane {
background-image: url('images/darkbackground.gif');
width: 326px;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}

#lefthead {
height: 132px;
width: 100%;
}

#leftheadfiller {
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
}

#leftheadlogo {
background-image: url('images/index_07.gif');
width: 71px;
height: 56px;
float: right;
}

#leftheaddivider {
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('images/lightbackground.gif');
float: right;
}

#lefttcontent {
height: 100%;
background-color: fuchsia;
}

#rightpane {
background-image: url('images/lightbackground.gif');
width: 540px;
height: 100%;
float: right;
}

#righthead {
height: 132px;
width: 100%;
}

#rightheadfiller {
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
}

#rightheadlogo {
background-image:url('images/index_09.gif');
width: 109px;
height: 56px;
float: right;
}

#rightheaddivider {
height: 1px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url('images/darkbackground.gif');
float: right;
}

#navigation {
margin-top: 2px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #A3A3A3;
font-size: 14px;
word-spacing: 44px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 18px;
}

#rightcontent {
padding-left: 6px;
background-color: fuchsia;
}

#close {
clear: both;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have this set up on a temporary folder on my local server at:

http://68.113.27.229/test

The two divs that I need to force the wrapper to grow are Leftcontent and Rightcontent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the parent div element.

If you don't want the overflowing content to be hidden, then try this:

Insert this as the last div inside the wrapper div.

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: Susam! You helped me last night, how swell of you to stop by again. If I add the hidden attribute the page loses its scroll bar. I assume you are saying add it to the Wrapper?

Comment: That's because you have set a height in the wrapper. Do really need a height there? The div would grow automatically as you fill content. I looked at your CSS and HTML and it is very hard to understand your question because the wrapper occupies 100% width and the aqua color covers the entire page. So, I am not sure what you mean when you say that it is not growing. Please provide a stripped down example that demonstrates only the issue and nothing else.

Comment: Will do, but there is a reason for the height on the wrapper. I need the left div to fill the page to 100% regardless if there is content in it or not. Without the wrapper having a set height of 100%, the left content wont grow.

Comment: Here is a picture to further illustrate my issue. The cyan color on the left is the left pane tag which is within the wrapper, but ISNT growing due to the wrapper not having a set height; http://i.imgur.com/9XApb.jpg

Comment: If you need the height, then use the other solution I have given. Doesn't `<div style="clear: both"></div>` work for you?

Comment: It does now that I removed the height as per you said.. THank you!