# CSS Child element losing parent background-color when floated or aligned

Tags: css, parent, background-color

```
<span class='parent'>Parent<span class='child'> and child</span></span>
```

If I do this:

```
.parent {
    background-color: green;
}
```

all of the text has a green background color. but if I add this:

```
.child {
   float: right;
}
```

the child no longer retains this property. I could do `background-color` on the child *but I need the space between the two to be highlighted*.

Is there a way to do this?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLWTd/

Comment: Adding overflow: hidden to the parent div element helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857120/parent-div-not-growing-with-floated-children

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Children never automatically inherit the parent's background color. The floated content is just *on top of* the parent's background. In this case, the parent's background only spans the amount of its actual inner text (which excludes the floated content).

Fortunately, with the way your structure is set up, you can explicitly [set the child's background to inherit](http://jsfiddle.net/UuQcJ/) the value of its parent.

```css
.child {
    float: right;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

---

**If you want the *entire line* to be that color**, you need to [use a block-level element](http://jsfiddle.net/JvUr5/). Try this:

```
<div class='parent'><span class='child'> and child</span>Parent</div>
```